# Must check last three check boxes to submit

Tags: javascript, php

Below is my list of check boxes that is part of my php form. I need to write a script where only the last three check boxes must be checked for the form to be successfully submitted. I have looked at other similar questions but can't seem to find what I am truly looking for and I am having trouble to write the script.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="Send email request">Would you like to receive weekly new via email?<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="Agree to T&C">I agree to the Terms and Conditions<br> 
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="No Criminal Records">I have no criminal associations<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="No Business with any other company">I have no personal or business relationship with any other company<br>
```

Comment: you can disable the submit button if they are unchecked using jquery.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to use any JavaScript.

Simply add a `required` attribute to the input elements.

```
<input type="checkbox" required="required" name="checkbox" value="Send email request">Would you like to receive weekly new via email?<br>
```

Take a look here for more info: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-checkbox-required/

If you want a custom message or response, then you will need to use JavaScript to handle this.

Comment: How exactly is this useful in this situation? There are 4 inputs, (any?) 3 of which must be selected to continue. Adding the `required` attribute means that it must be checked in order to continue. So, with 4 inputs, how do you propose to make use of this attribute for an arbitrary selection of 3 of them?

Comment: "I need to write a script where only the last three check boxes must be checked for the form to be successfully submitted"

I think the last three inputs **must** be checked for the form to submit. I don't think it's an arbitrary selection of them, it is all of them, unless I am misunderstanding his question. But with the data provided for those last three inputs, it seems they should all be required :-)

Comment: Oh dear. Nope, not you misreading the question - it was me. `SamP.rep++;`

Comment: @SamP I didn't know it was that simple. Can this 'required' attribute be checked server-side? (Sorry, I might of forgotten to mention that).

Comment: In the form POST data, simply check if the checkbox values are true. If they are not, reject the POST.

Comment: @SamP What do you mean by this? Could you please explain a little more?

Comment: It depends on the server you're using, but you will get an object representing your form when you POST. You can check that the properties relating to the required checkboxes have values true. If they are false, have the server throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use jQuery to check if it is indeed that the last 3 checkboxes or are checked (required) before submission. Consider this example:

```
<form method="POST" action="index.php" id="form">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Send email request">Would you like to receive weekly new via email?<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Agree to T&C">I agree to the Terms and Conditions<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="No Criminal Records">I have no criminal associations<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="No Business with any other company">I have no personal or business relationship with any other company<br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>

<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form').submit(function(e){
        var count = 0;
        var required_indeces = [1,2,3];
        $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(index, element){
            if($.inArray(index, required_indeces) !== -1 && $(this).is(':checked')) {
                count++;
            }
        });

        if(count < 3) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The checkboxes need to have different names. Using the same name means you are only storing the value of the last checked box. Try one of these two options (for PHP):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Send email request">Would you like to receive weekly new via email?<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Agree to T&C">I agree to the Terms and Conditions<br> 
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="No Criminal Records">I have no criminal associations<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="No Business with any other company">I have no personal or business relationship with any other company<br>
```

Then, to check that the last three are checked:

```
if (!isset($_POST['checkbox'][1], $_POST['checkbox'][2], $_POST['checkbox'][3])) {
    echo 'One of the last 3 NOT checked!';
}
```

**OR:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="Send email request">Would you like to receive weekly new via email?<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" value="Agree to T&C">I agree to the Terms and Conditions<br> 
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" value="No Criminal Records">I have no criminal associations<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4" value="No Business with any other company">I have no personal or business relationship with any other company<br>
```

Then:

```
if (!isset($_POST['checkbox2'], $_POST['checkbox3'], $_POST['checkbox4'])) {
    echo 'One of the last 3 NOT checked!';
}
```